# How can I add content dynamically in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have controller with a page named list.html.erb

when a user clicks a link I want to append content dynamically to the page and execute  javascript afterwards.
is it possible to have a method which renders a js.erb file and I put into this file the variables containing the content?

best phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described there: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to you need to use

```
link_to 'Something', 'somewhere', remote: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. It may not be the best course of action, though.

If you're enhancing the functionality of the view through Javascript, it's probably better to keep the code in Javascript rather than Ruby-generated Javascript.

Make a simple HTML link that GETs the new content from a controller in the JSON format or even as an HTML snippet. Use something like $.ajax and its success callback function to append said response to the element in the page.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "whatever/here",
  type: "GET",
  data_type: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    $("#element_in_question").append(response); //if HTML; if JSON, parse and build the HTML
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, message) {
    //indicate failure somehow
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a partial in your list.html.erb and display the partial on changing some content on the page list.html.erb. For example considering your list.html.erb file, you can include the following in your page

```
<form_for :something, :remote => true, :method => get :url => {:action => "partial"} do |f| %>

//write your code here

<%=f.submit%> //here you can have :onchange in the form_for tag if you do not want a submit button
```

write a division for partial in your list page as below

```
<div id="partial">
</div>
```

write a partial.js.erb file like this:

```
$('#partial').html("<%=j render "partial" %>");
```

create a `_partial.html.erb` file with the content you want to add the list.html.erb dynamically.

in the controller, add the following code:

```
def partial
//write your code here
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
```

This will display the added content in the div tag of your list page with div id "partial"